# Limit of a probability distribution function times $x$

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Let $p(x)$ be a probability density function (i.e. non-negative, integrating to 1).

Assume further that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}p(x)=0$.

Is it always true that

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[xp(x)\right] - \lim_{x\to-\infty}\left[xp(x)\right]=0?
$$

If so, why? If not, what is minimal set assumptions on $p(x)$ that will render the statement true?

Comment: A PDF has not necessarily limits $0$ at $\pm\infty$. A fortiori the assertion you seek to prove cannot hold in full generality.

Comment: That's my assumption on a PDF, so we can hold it true. Is the main statement still not always true?

Comment: @dmytro : Consider the function $f(x)=\text{constant} \cdot \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }n<x<n+(1/2^n)\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb Z^{+}, \\  0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$  This does not approach $0$ as $x\to\infty$, but it's integral is $1$ if the constant has the right value, and it is everywhere non-negative, so it's a probability density function. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, sorry, I didn't really understad what you was trying to say. It still looks like your $f(x)$ indeed approaches 0 as $x\to\infty$. Anyway, I'm only interested in answering this question for "well-behaved" $p(x)$, i.e. such that they tend to 0 as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @dmytro : It does not approach $0$, since no matter how big $x_0$ gets, there is some $x>x_0$ such that $f(x)=1$.  If a function approaches $0$, then for $x$ bigger than some number you'd always have $|f(x)|<1/100$, and for $x$ bigger than some other number you'd always have $|f(x)<1/1000000$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As to minimal assumptions, probably nothing that is not closely related to the desired conclusion. But after a while monotone will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some counterexamples to the assertion that every PDF $p$ converges to zero at $\pm\infty$ are explained in the comments, a smooth variant is a "sum-of-bumps" PDF such as$$p(x)=\sum_ng\left(\frac{x-x_n}{\sigma_n}\right),$$ where $g$ is the standard gaussian density, $\sigma_n\gt0$ for every $n$, $\sum\limits_n\sigma_n=1$, and $x_n\to\infty$.

Then $p$ is indeed a PDF (*can you check this?*), and, for every $n$, $p(x_n)\geqslant g(0)=1/\sqrt{2\pi},$ hence $p$ does not converge to zero at $\infty$.

When $p$ does converge to $0$ at $\infty$, the fact that $xp(x)\to0$ is not guaranteed either, as similar counterexamples show. However:

> Let $p$ denote a PDF such that, for $x$ large enough, $x\mapsto p(x)$ is non increasing. Then $xp(x)\to0$.

To show this, note that, for $x$ large enough, $$\int_{x/2}^{\infty}p(u)\,\mathrm du\geqslant\int_{x/2}^{x}p(u)\,\mathrm du\geqslant\int_{x/2}^{x}p(x)\,\mathrm du=\frac12xp(x).$$ The LHS goes to zero hence  $xp(x)\to0$, QED. A similar result holds for the asymptotics when $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: The positive result in this answer is mentioned by @AndréNicolas in a comment to the question.

Comment: thanks for the proof of Andre's comment. I'm working with stable stochastic ode's with small noise, so $p(x, t)\to 0$ is a very resonable assumption. I have a feeling that nondecreasing $p(x)$ for large $x$ should also be reasonable, but i'm quite sure about that one though...

Answer (score 1):

Note that any pdf that approaches $0$ at a rate of $1/x$ or slower will fail this condition generically. Trivially, $p(-x)=-p(x)$ satisfies this condition. Otherwise, you need $p(x)$ to converge to 0 at a rate faster than $1/x$, for example, at rate $1/x^2$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x p(x)=0$, as does $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} x p(x)$.